# Angular 2 cache dedicated service vs embedded?

Tags: rest, angular, caching

We are working on a project where we start to have heavy cache management logic which is included in http services (eg. **EmployeeService**, **DepartmentService**, ....)

Which option would be better ?

- **Embedded cache logic in model service class**.
- **dedicated cache managemenet service class** (eg. EmplyeeCacheManagerService).

Answer (score 0):

Your question is too generic and it's just a matter of preference. If you want global state access, then use a cache management service or even better something like Redux. Otherwise, use stae in the individual services.